# how to convert integer to bool in html?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I have below code where hold.Property__r.Holds__c is a numeric value due to which I am getting error. Can someone suggest how we convert this field to bool

```
<div if:true={hold.Property__r.Holds__c} class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning-badge class="slds-text-heading_medium" label="On Hold"></lightning-badge>
                    </div>
                    <div if:false={hold.Property__r.Holds__c} class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning-badge class="slds-text-heading_medium" label="Error - Incorrect Hold Status"></lightning-badge>
                    </div>
```

Comment: try using [getters and setters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_getters_setters), manually processing data

Comment: And such a getter could be as simple as `return !!this.hold.Property__r.Holds__c` (though perhaps with a safe navigation operator in case any part of the path is null like `return !!this.hold?.Property__r?.Holds__c`).

Comment: @OlehBerehovskyi I dont have much experience on this.. Could you please elaborate on the context above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @OlehBerehovskyi said, use a getter that coerces the number into a boolean. The assumption here is that you care if the "holds" value is non-zero.

First, add the following getter to your LWC:

```
get holds() {
    return !!this.hold?.Property__r?.Holds__c;
}
```

And update your template to use:

```
<div if:true={holds} class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
   ...
```

This works by:

1. Using "!!" to get the "truthiness" of a number; it first does a "not" of a number, which is a boolean indicating whether it is zero (the "falsiness"), then notting that again to indicate whether the number is non-zero (the "truthiness").
2. Using safe navigation, which stops the traversal of the path if there's a null/undefined; note that the "!!" still works here because it gets the truthiness of null/undefined in the same way it would for a number (or string etc.).
3. Using the getter in the template.

Comment: Thanks... this explains a lot !!